# How can make imageView full screen android

Tags: android, imageview, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I try to make imageView displayed in full screen after user click it.

For example now imageView like that:

[image]

And what I need to do like that:

[image]

How can make that?

Also how we can make zoom to it?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: @MohammedAlaa  Hi brother I try this link its work but there are one point I don't know how they do it. background color black how they do it in this example?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imageView;

boolean isImageFitToScreen;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                isImageFitToScreen=false;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }else{
                isImageFitToScreen=true;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

add this in your ImageView in xml :

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Hi brother .. I was try this it's don't as I need .. this code make size of image is changing in same place. I don't know how explain that actually but is different.

Comment: I need  do for example like twitter app if you are see image in time line you will see it smal but if you are click it you will see true size of his photos

Comment: some thing like that you know that system in all app now almost

Comment: also in aliexpress app same that

Comment: try to show it in dialog (after click on Image). You can display it as you wish. Or use existing photo libraries.

Comment: If I show it in dialog that will be show different.I try to make it like my question. the image in center and above and down black screen if you are see to the example in my question you will understand what I need

Comment: And sorry but I am a new developer with little experience